# History-search-backward for ruby irb

Tags: ruby, irb

I would like the `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` mechanisms from bash for the ruby irb, which allow me to cycle through matching history entries based on a already given input.

Is this feature even available? I already enabled the IRB history and searched the documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set input-meta Off
set convert-meta On

Meta-p: history-search-backward
Meta-n: history-search-forward
```

(change the last two lines to use keys of your choice.) Restart `irb`/`pry`. Enjoy.

---

*Sidenote:* consider trying [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) instead of `irb` (with [`pry-history`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History) plugin installed.) It’s worth it.

Comment: totally forgot about pry. I didn't use your meta settings but rebinded my up/down arrow keys to do that. `"\e[A": history-search-backward`  Will that have any weird sideeffects as inputrc is not really irb specific ;)?

Comment: No, it won’t. It’s a system-wide setting, just be aware of that.